# Java BigDecimal memory usage?

Tags: java, memory, memory-management, bigdecimal

Is there a guideline for estimating the amount of memory consumed by a `BigDecimal`?

Looking for something similar to these [guidelines](http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/memory/string_memory_usage.shtml) for estimating `String` memory usage.

Comment: Much the same with a bigger constant. Of course, like `String`, it is implementation dependent.

Comment: Did you read this one: http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/javatips/jw-javatip130.html

Answer (score 27, accepted):

If you look at the fields in the source for `BigDecimal` there is:

```
BigDecimal:
  long intCompact +8 bytes
  int precision +4 bytes
  int scale +4 bytes
  String stringCache +?
  BigInteger intVal +?

BigInteger:
  int bitCount +4 bytes
  int bitLength +4 bytes
  int firstNonzeroIntNum +4 bytes
  int lowestSetBit +4 bytes
  int signum +4 bytes
  int[] mag +?
```

The comment for `stringCache` says

> Used to store the canonical string representation, if computed.

Assuming you don't call `.toString()`, it will remain zero bytes. Hence `BigDecimal` is (8+4+4)=16 bytes + `BigInteger`.

`BigInteger` itself is 4+4+4+4+4=20 bytes + `mag`.

20+16 gives total of 36 bytes plus the magnitude, which is always the minimum number of bits necessary to represent the full integer. For a number `n` it will need `log2(n)` bits, which can be converted to ints. You should be using about:

```
36 + Ceiling(log2(n)/8.0) bytes
```

(note this doesn't include any of the other object descriptor overhead as your example link for strings does, but it should give you a good general idea.)

Comment: Keep in mind that 'stringCache' and 'intVal' will have reference pointers (jvm impl dependent 4 or 8 bytes). Also remember the min 12byte object header overhead ('BigInteger' and 'BigDecimal', int[]) and finally 8byte align (round up) all object sizes.

Answer (score 2):

If you dig into the internals of `BigDecimal` you'll see that it uses a compact representation if the significand is <= `Long.MAX_VALUE`.  Hence, the memory usage can vary depending on the actual values you're representing.

Comment: What is the compact representation?