# How much space does BigInteger use?

Tags: java, biginteger

How many bytes of memory does a BigInteger object use in general ?

Comment: How many bytes of memory does an array object use in general? ;-)

Comment: here ya go: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/math/BigInteger.java

Comment: read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9368764/calculate-size-of-object-in-java

Comment: At least two minimum-sized objects.  I think the minimum object size on most platforms is 32 bytes.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

BigInteger internally uses an `int[]` to represent the huge numbers you use.
Thus it really **depends on the size of the number you store in it**. The `int[]` will grow if the current number doesn't fit in dynamically.

To get the number of bytes your `BigInteger` instance *currently* uses, you can make use of the `Instrumentation` interface, especially [`getObjectSize(Object)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/instrument/Instrumentation.html#getObjectSize%28java.lang.Object%29).

```
import java.lang.instrument.Instrumentation;

public class ObjectSizeFetcher {
    private static Instrumentation instrumentation;

    public static void premain(String args, Instrumentation inst) {
        instrumentation = inst;
    }

    public static long getObjectSize(Object o) {
        return instrumentation.getObjectSize(o);
    }
}
```

To convince yourself, take a look at the [source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/math/BigInteger.java), where it says:

```
/**
 * The magnitude of this BigInteger, in <i>big-endian</i> order: the
 * zeroth element of this array is the most-significant int of the
 * magnitude.  The magnitude must be "minimal" in that the most-significant
 * int ({@code mag[0]}) must be non-zero.  This is necessary to
 * ensure that there is exactly one representation for each BigInteger
 * value.  Note that this implies that the BigInteger zero has a
 * zero-length mag array.
 */
final int[] mag;
```

Answer (score 9):

Following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2501176/java-bigdecimal-memory-usage) post:

```
BigInteger:
  int bitCount +4 bytes
  int bitLength +4 bytes
  int firstNonzeroIntNum +4 bytes
  int lowestSetBit +4 bytes
  int signum +4 bytes
  int[] mag +?
```

That's a total of 20 bytes + the integer array. An integer array of length N has size 4N + 24 (Array overhead + 4 bytes/integer).

In total this makes 4N + 44 bytes, depending on how big your number is. Don't forget the reference to an object also uses memory.

Edit: 16 additional bytes as object overhead, brings it to 4N + 60 bytes. Adding padding to this (each object uses a multiple of 8 bytes) we get an additional 4 bytes.

This results in **4N + 64** bytes.

Comment: You also need to include two object headers -- at least 8 bytes each, likely 16.

Comment: @HotLicks: You are correct, I've added both the header and the padding. Although, come to think of it: could you explain me how you get to two headers instead of just one?

Comment: You get two headers because the array is necessarily a separate object (except in the "classic JVM" of IBM iSeries).

Comment: Are you referring to the `int[]` array? I believe I already covered that with the 24 bytes allocated to it.

Comment: OK -- It's not obvious you're accounting for it... you have to assume.

Comment: I think you did fail to account for the pointer to the int array.

Comment: That's true, nor have I accounted for the references to the other ints

Comment: You don't need references for the int fields.  But you do need a reference for the array, since it's a separate object.

Answer (score 3):

Using VisualVM retained-size on a JVM 64-bit, here are some concrete numbers  :

- BigInteger **1** digit = **70B** (ex: new BigInteger("9"))
- BigInteger **20** digits = **80B** (ex: new BigInteger("12345678901234567890"))
- BigInteger **100** digits = **112B**

For comparison :

- **Long** (wrapper class) = **24B** (but Long is limited to 18-19 digits)
- **long** (primitive) = **8B**

So `BigInteger` is at least 3x heavier than a `Long` and 10x heavier than a `long`. So use BigInteger only when you really need it!

Comment: @BertKing as mentionned I've used VisualVM (but there are plenty of other tools) to take a heap dump

Answer (score 1):

Java object size depends on its fields. These are BigInteger fields

```
final int signum;
final int[] mag;
private int bitCount;
private int bitLength;
private int lowestSetBit;
private int firstNonzeroIntNum;
```

we can calculate the size of a BigInteger instance as

```
8 + 4 + (12 + mag.length * 4) + 4 + 4 + 4 + 4  ~= 40 + mag.length * 4
```

see http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/memory/object_memory_usage.shtml.

Comment: You left out header sizes.

Comment: why? 8 for BigInteger and 12 for int array, seems OK

Comment: OK -- you didn't call out those in your list.