# Handling caching of very large set

Tags: java, file, memory, set

I have a `Set` of `BigInteger` that I want to cache.
This Set can go up to `~100K` size.

The application i'm using is quite light : it does not have a lot of memory (heap about `256mb`) and does not use a database (the team is considering it for later, but now it is not possible).

Upon initialization, it receives a big `array` of `BigInteger` that needs to be stored in a `File` for future use.

The application then needs to check if a particular `BigInteger` is stored into the given file.

Considering the memory implications, what would i need to do in order to store efficiently these values then check if a given value is present in the file ?

Comment: Order them and do a binary search. If you want to do something fancy, then you could use a Btree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume each BigInt takes up 20 bytes. Then 100k of them take up ~2MB, less than 1% of heap size. Hopefully it's something you can afford to just keep in RAM.

I'd sort them and put into an array, then use [binary search](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#binarySearch%28T[],%20int,%20int,%20T,%20java.util.Comparator%29) to efficiently check if a particular value is in the array.

Update: an array is most compact representation; a tree would waste 12 to 24 bytes per item just on three pointers.

Comment: 20 bytes is a lot less than I'd expect for a typical `BigInteger`.  In fact, I'm not even sure the smallest `BigInteger` fits in 20 bytes.

Comment: @LouisWasserman: still it could be a noticeable percent. The payload of a reasonably small `BigInteger` is probably 16 bytes (two 64-bit words), plus 4-8 bytes of object header (think 'VMT pointer').

Answer (score 0):

The size of a BigInt is [variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2501176/java-bigdecimal-memory-usage), but you can assume that 100K BigInt object won't use more than 10MB. The easiest way to store them in order to search anyone quickly is using a TreeSet, which is a implementation of a SortedSet.