# How much space does a spark decimal column really consume?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

For a `double` data type it is stated in the [docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-datatypes.html), that it is consuming exactly 8 bytes, but for `decimal`, there is no such clear statement. In SQL Server - as comparison - it is stated, that decimal takes between 5 - 17 bytes depending on the chosen precision. see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/sql/t-sql/data-types/decimal-and-numeric-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#arguments).

How much space is decimal consuming in spark?

Comment: The docs clearly state that decimal is backed by Java's `BigDecimal`. It is an arbitrary-precision type that consists of a `BigInteger` scaled value and a 32-bit integer scale. `BigInteger` could be anything from a single byte to many bytes, so it all depends on the desired precision.

Comment: Ok, I just read a bit through this [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2501176/java-bigdecimal-memory-usage) and `decimal` appears to be huge compared to `double` or `float`. At least 10x the size for ordinary currency values. I really need to check, if I could switch to these ones instead.