# Is DECIMAL in Apache Hive a fixed length type?

Tags: java, hadoop, hive

How to get the length of `DECIMAL` in Apache Hive, if it is a fixed length type, such as 16 byte or not?

I did not found information in documentation, if it has some methods to get the length, such as some functions, or if it has some rules for different accuracy.

Answer (score 0):

> ***How to get the length of `DECIMAL` in Apache Hive, if it is a fixed length type, such as 16 byte or not?***

According [Apache Hive - LanguageManual Types](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/hive/languagemanual+types#LanguageManualTypes-DecimalsdecimalDecimals)

> *The `DECIMAL` type in Hive is based on Java's `BigDecimal` which is used for representing immutable arbitrary precision decimal numbers in Java.*

and Java 8 [`BigDecimal`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDe%5Dcimal.html)

> *A BigDecimal consists of an arbitrary precision integer* unscaled value *and a 32-bit integer* scale.

This leads to, if that is question, [Java BigDecimal memory usage](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2501339/6771046).

And the question about

> ***... or if it has some rules for different accuracy.***

leads to [Double vs. BigDecimal?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3413493/6771046)

> *A `BigDecimal` is an exact way of representing numbers. A `Double` has a certain precision.*